# java virtual machine: type information

Tags: java, jvm, virtual-machine

I recently read about JVM specification according to Artima Inside the JVM 2-nd Ed. One of the chapters mentioned type storing in the Java runtime and it said that:

> An instance of class `java.lang.Class` is created by the Java virtual machine for every type it loads. The virtual machine must in some way associate a reference to the Class instance for a type with the type's data in the method area.

I am a little bit confused, as I always thought that `Class` files where places on the method area that contained type information. Is there some other place that Java stores type info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as it says `an instance of java.lang.Class` is created. This means an **Object** representing the class file is placed on the heap, as well as the `Class` file in the method area.

This is the `Class` object that is returned when you call `getClass()` on an Object.

Comment: Yeah, but it says it is associating the REFERENCE to Class file with type info. But Class is type info, why does it needs reference to itself?

Comment: The `Class` Object that is created must contain a reference to the Class data in the method area. Two different entities. It's just so that a connection can be made between the two when information is needed. The connection is not visible programatically.

Comment: SO, when we try to run `instanceof` in Java, the pointer on the object points to type data on the method area or to the singleton `Class` object on the heap of that type?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `instanceof` only uses the `Class` object on the heap. It will compare two `Class` Objects to see if they are identical. The reference to the method area will only be used internally by the JVM to perform operations such as fetching items from the constant pool or method resolution.